# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5 false class error

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

After updating to latest IntelliJ 2016.2.5 (community), when I create new class that requires import of new library in class or some times when I have code errors, it shows a red line under the class name, but after fixing the error, the red line is still present but the class works fine.

**Example** in one of the scenarios I have had a working class I have previously worked on with jfree chart example, I have copied the class to my new project, and I added the `org.jfree` dependency in Maven, after updating maven, I was able to build and run the class with out problems, but it kept the red line.

When IntelliJ need to make mass error line updates, it does not refresh the red line even thus it is fixed.

> Note:
>
> - This behavior doesn't happen for small error issues
> - This issue didn't occur in previous versions.
> - Rebuilding and cleaning project does not help.

**My Solution** right now is to restart IDE.

**My Question** is this a bug? Or is it some setting I have to do on this version?

**Software info:**

- Build #IC-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016
- JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2 x86
- JVM: OpenJDK Server VM
- On Windows 10 with latest updates

Here is example of the error:

[image]

Comment: Are you running in Power Save mode?  That'd be one thing which wouldn't cause those validations to refresh frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I installed the latest version IntelliJ 2016.3 I have not faced this problem. So I assume this must be a bug that is solved on this version.